# Reading JSON file with AJAX and storing data to an array

Tags: javascript, ajax

All I am trying to do is reading an JSON file with data format as shown below and extract only id from nodes and store it in an array.

```
{"nodes":[
{"id":"1057457211927117824", "age":"20", "name":"a", "loaded":true},
{"id":"1057459284189970433", "age":"20", "name":"b", "loaded":true}
]
"links":[
{"id":"l01", "from":"1057457210467540992", "to":"1057455883972722689", "type":"friend"},
{"id":"l02", "from":"1057457271331057664", "to":"1057451606344646656", "type":"friend"}
]}
```

Below is the code I tried but its not working.

```
var node_id = []; 
$.getJSON("data/newData.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        node_id.push(value[0]['id']); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you can look at the code below:

```js
var jsonData = {
"nodes":[
  {"id":"1057457211927117824", "age":"20", "name":"a", "loaded":true},
  {"id":"1057459284189970433", "age":"20", "name":"b", "loaded":true}],
"links":[
  {"id":"l01", "from":"1057457210467540992", "to":"1057455883972722689", "type":"friend"},
  {"id":"l02", "from":"1057457271331057664", "to":"1057451606344646656", "type":"friend"}
]};

var node_id = []; 
$.each(jsonData.nodes, function (index, value) {
    node_id.push(value['id']); 
});

console.log(node_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was trying to do.Thanks a lot.